# Unknown WooCommerce API version in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, woocommerce-rest-api

- Wordpress version : 5.3
- WooCommerce version: 3.8.1
- WooCommerce.NET version: 0.7.2

First I was trying WooCommerce.NET version: 0.8.0

I used RestAPI class:

```cs
 public class MyRestAPI:RestAPI
    {
        public MyRestAPI(string url, string key, string secret, bool authorizedHeader = true,
            Func<string, string> jsonSerializeFilter = null,
            Func<string, string> jsonDeserializeFilter = null,
            Action<HttpWebRequest> requestFilter = null) : base(url, key, secret, authorizedHeader, jsonSerializeFilter, jsonDeserializeFilter, requestFilter)
        {
        }

        public override T DeserializeJSon<T>(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonString);
        }

        public override string SerializeJSon<T>(T t)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t);
        }
    }
```

but page is showing:

> Unknown WooCommerce API version in c#

Comment: Please describe what is the expected output and where the output should come from. Can we look at the WooCommerce API that you are using?

Comment: Which page shows `Unknown WooCommerce API version`

Comment: a page that was running means i am working on customer and customer view showing that error

Comment: ya its standard api from woocommerce 
https://www.example.com//wp-json/wc/v3/customers

Comment: the Get api working but post api not working proper .its Post API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough Context in the question, But i'm going to say the Error is relatively self explanatory, The WooCommerce  API has 3 Version.

Make sure your request is Specifying which version you which to use.

An Example

```
 /wp-json/wc/v3
```

Make sure you'r stating v1 /v2 /v3.

Comment: Thanks for your ans but i already checked all versions but now i am happy i tried another way that implemented thx

Comment: I'd recommend if you get stuck again have a look at https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET

Its a Wrapper for .Net and it simplifies alot of the work.